# Getting Failed connections after storing ConnectionString in Azure Web App Settings as opposed to web.config

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, entity-framework-6, azure-sql-database, azure-web-app-service

Over Christmas I changed our web application (MVC,EF6, SQL Azure) to use a connectionstring setting from Azure's web application property settings rather than in the web.config. This was to serve 2 purposes:

1) More secure

2) Help prevent accidental repointing of apps to incorrect DB.

Since doing this I have discovered 40% of our connections are failing. Now this might be co-incidental with an Azure issue, as when doing this on another SQL Azure server I use, I could not repeat this.

The ConnectionString data that I have entered into Azure is:

**ApplicationCS**

Data Source=tcp:live1-server.database.windows.net,1433;Initial Catalog=Live-DB;User ID=user@live1-server;Password=12345

**EntitiesCS**

metadata=res://AppNamespace/app.csdl|res://AppNamespace/app.ssdl|res://AppNamespace/app.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string="Data Source=tcp:live1-server.database.windows.net,1433;Initial Catalog=Live-DB;User ID=user@live1-server;Password=12345"

**Elmah**

Data Source=tcp:live2-server.database.windows.net,1433;Initial Catalog=ElmahDB;User ID=user@live2-server.database.windows.net;Password=9999

I have changed pertinant details for obvious security reasons.

So my question:

1) Has anyone experienced failed connections when using Azure to store Connection Strings for Web Apps.

2) Do my details look correct. I assume they do, since the application will connect, but not all of the time.

This issue may be co-incidental, but to have a "failing connection" issue on a Azure DB Server from the 23rd until now seems a long time if it is caused by an Azure infrastructural issue.

Thanks in advance.

EDIT

I have analysed the event_log via:

```
SELECT      
        [Date From] = EL.[start_time],
        [Date To] = EL.[end_time],
        [Database Name] = EL.[database_name],
        [Event Type] = EL.[event_type],
        [Event Sub Type] = EL.[event_subtype_desc],
        [Description] = EL.[description],
        EL.event_count,
        [Additional Data] = EL.additional_data
        FROM sys.event_log EL
        WHERE EL.event_type != 'connection_successful'
        AND EL.event_subtype_desc != 'idle_connection_timeout'
        ORDER BY [Date From] DESC
```

I notice that I am getting a lot of "login_failed_for_user" errors here although my web app seems to work fine, although more slowly. These errors started after I changed the SQL Azure password using the Azure Portal. I cannot tell from the "event_log" what is causing these failures. All the scheduled processes work fine and anyway these are only overnight. I am getting these errors every 5 mins or so. The new password is much stronger ie 20 characters and random. Would this be causing SQL Azure a problem. The intermittent nature of this error is strange.

Comment: You didn't specified the error..but you can look at  `sys.event_log ` DMV and know causes for failures,by correlating timestamps with failed time stamps

Comment: The error is "login_failed_for_user". I do not really understand your comment "correlating timestamps with failed time stamps". Thanks for your help thus far. Incidentally I think I may have tracked the caused by a sudden idea which is looking to be correct. Basically I had a deployment slot which was pointing to the same database, but was unused, but had an application setting of "Always On" set to "on" which causes Azure to ping the site which was causing these attempted DB accesses. I stopped this slot, and the event_log is looking good so far.

Comment: i meant to say,correlate your login failures timings with time stamps from DMV

Comment: OK, DMVs are new to me, so will investigate, and thanks

Comment: False hope..... Event_log just refreshed, still getting the issue.... hmmm...

Comment: eventlog stores data for 14 days as per my understanding

Comment: scroll down to event aggregation section :https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn270018.aspx

Comment: I have also noticed that the event_log displays for each 5 minute period. I have also noticed that I get the same failure number for master as my AppDb which is about 5 per 5 min period, but the Master failures are always identical to the AppDb failures. I never access Master directly in any ConnectionString or Job etc. So puzzled by this.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132406/discussion-between-thegameiswar-and-samjolly).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This does sound coincidental. Either the connection string is bad, and everything should fail, or it's good and it should work identically whether you hard code it in web.config or use Azure settings.

Putting it in Azure settings causes it to get injected into the .NET config system at runtime. At that point, the two cases are basically indistinguishable.

Comment: thank you for the reply. So basically you are saying that putting it in Azure should not affect it at all. I believe it is best practice anyway.

Comment: Yes, it is what we suggest. I was only referring to it making no difference in term of the failure you are getting. I suspect that if you put it back in web.config, you'll continue to see the same failure.

Comment: I have tried and monitored DB activity on my QA SQL Azure server and this seems fine. So I am wondering whether there is something wrong with my LIVE DB server. So I have created another SQL Azure Server where I will import a copy of the problem DB instance and see if the problem carries on, on the new DB server. Thanks again.

Comment: I have added an EDIT to my question with extra information.

Comment: The only thing I have done to solve this is to create a new SQL Azure Server and export the old DB and then import this onto the new DB Server. When I run the same codebase, using the deployment slot of the live web app, I get no errors. I am also using the Azure ConnectionString settings feature. Throughout today, on live, the failed connections have been 5 for Master and 5 for AppDB, both identical, per 5 minute period in Event_Log. So very consistent which implies some automated process is doing this. Also, just thought of this, but would SQL Server not lock the account?

Comment: I think for this question, we need to take it as far as answering whether it being in Azure settings vs web.config is a factor. Once we confirm that it isn't, if you are having connection string issues **regardless of which way it's stored**, you should ask a separate question that focuses on that and leaves out the whole part about how it's stored.

Comment: Fair comment, thank you for your help. I do not believe there is a difference, and have concluded there is another cause. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Experienced similar problem with a PHP app hosted in Azure Web Apps with MySQL database. After changing the connection string to point to a different database and deleting previously used database, backups started failing with error it can't connect to the database. Error message indicated it was using the connection string to old database.
"Reset Configuration" for backups seems to have worked!